# Persona - onRenderPrimaryText - pass addt'l parameters?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I'm looping through a list of users and would like to modify the Persona name to hyperlink to a specific page.

```
          {this.props.users.map((u: any) => {

            //u has a property called u.ProfileUrl

            return (
              <div className={styles.personaTile}>
                <Persona
                  text={u.DisplayName}
                  size={PersonaSize.size48}
                  className={styles.persona}
                  imageInitials="true"
                  onRenderPrimaryText={this._onRenderPrimaryText}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

How do I reference a value in my `onRenderPrimaryText` method from the `this.props.user` mapping object of `u`?  I don't understand how to either pass it as a parameter or reference it from props. Do I use `props.componentRef`?

```
  private _onRenderPrimaryText = (props: IPersonaProps): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <div className={styles.personaName}>
        <a href={  ???????  }>{props.text}</a>   // <-- How do I reference the u.ProfileUrl here?
      </div>
    );
    // tslint:disable-next-line:semicolon
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of passing that extra data so that you can have it available in your custom renderer, but with a little JS closure magic I came up with [this working solution](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/GRgOdaB). All you will still have to play with is the typing if you care about this in your project and the styling. From a really quick look both are doable in way or another.

```
const PersonaCustomRenderExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const personas = examplePersonas.map(examplePersona => {
    const customPrimaryTextRenderer = getCustomPrimaryTextRenderer(examplePersona);

    return (
      <Persona
        {...examplePersona}
        size={PersonaSize.size72}
        presence={PersonaPresence.offline}
        onRenderPrimaryText={customPrimaryTextRenderer}
        styles={{ root: { margin: "0 0 10px 0" } }}
        imageAlt="Annie Lindqvist, status is offline."
      />
    );
  });

  return <Stack tokens={{ childrenGap: 10 }}>{personas}</Stack>;
};

function getCustomPrimaryTextRenderer(persona) {
   return (props: IPersonaProps): JSX.Element => {
     return (
       <div>
         <a href={persona.profileUrl}>{props.secondaryText}</a>
       </div>
     );
  };
}
```

Comment: Very helpful!  Your time is much appreciated with this solution.

Comment: Likewise. Very helpful solution!